# I've got 2 questions regarding sqlite3 queries using 2 tables

Tags: sqlite

[image: Questions are based on this image]

A) List each lecturer together with each module they teach and the number of students studying that module, in order of the lecturer name.

B) Output the number of modules in which everyone passed the module (assuming pass mark is 40).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For A, you need to join the 2 tables and then `group by lecturer, module` and count the number of rows for each group (each row corresponds to a student):

```
select t.lecturer, t.module, count(*) numberofstudents
from teaches t inner join studies s
on s.module = t.module
group by t.lecturer, t.module
order by t.lecturer
```

For B, use `NOT EXISTS` to find the modules where all grades are `>= 40` and count them:

```
select count(distinct module) numberofmodules
from studies s
where not exists (
  select 1 from studies 
  where module = s.module and grade < 40
)
```

Comment: You saved the day. Thank you!